# revealjs with Rmarkdown - setting fonts and drawing lines

Tags: html, css, r-markdown, reveal.js

I'm using the `revealjs` library in R to build a set of slides. I would like to:

1. customise font color
2. put a dotted border line that separates headers and footers

I've managed to set the colour of text that appears on a slide by adding the following into the CSS file:

```
#mycustom {
  color: blue;
}
```

Then in the markdown document, I would use it loke so:

```
## Slide 2 {#mycustom}

XYZ

- a
- b
- c
```

This changes the colour of everything except for "Slide 2". I'd like to control the headers as well, and ideally I'd like to be able to set these colours in the CSS once.

As for my second issue, I've added the following to the CSS file:

```
.reveal .header {
  padding: 1px; 
  border: 1px dashed orange;
}
```

Then I modified the revealjs template that can be found under `<R_DIR/library/revealjs/rmarkdown/templates/revealjs_presentation/resources/default.html>` and added `<div class="header"></div>` under `<div class="slides">` but the result looks disappointing: I'm getting a small double dashed line as shown in the attached image.

If you have a suggestion on how to improve this, please let me know.

Many thanks!

[image: unsuccessful attempt]

Comment: I added an answer for problem 1. I am not sure what you exactly mean there. Should the dotted line be betwwen "Slide 1" and the rest of the slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your first problem, why not just use

```
<style>
#myCustom > h1, #myCustom > h2 {
 color: #FF0000;
}

/* or if you want to change all h1: */
h1 {
  color: #00FF00 !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, your answer helped. As for my second question, apologies for not providing a clear explanation. I was struggling with the double dotted line, whereas I was only looking for a single line. I was able to achieve the desired effect by setting padding:0px. Thanks again for your help.